# Show text when a dropdown option is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a way to display a some text based on the drop down item selected by the user, in the "result" div below. I know how to do this with a normal input field but I am having trouble understanding how to pass in "option values" into the javascript function. This is what I tried so far...

In the code below, I am simply trying to successfully pass whatever drop down item value is selected into the javascript function and print out the name of that value in the "result" div... once I am able to do that, I will implement the 'tip' feature described above.

My Markup:

```
<select onChange="dropdownTip(this.value)" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">veggies</option>
    <option value="animals_search">animals</option>
    <option value="all_search">all</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdownTip(value){
        document.getElementByID("result").innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, you just have a typo: `document.getElementByID(..)` should be `document.getElementById(..)`.

Comment: thats is the answer I needed;) I am new to javascript. One thing I don't like is that having a typo can result in hours of debugging and is hard to troubleshoot. Thank you very much for pointing that out, your comment is my solution.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you wanted? check the fiddle below

> http://jsfiddle.net/b6ydm/

Comment: Yes, thank you. One question though, what is the importance of console.log(value) ??? how come it does not work without it?

Comment: actually I used it just to test if the value was passed to the function or not.. you can remove it ..not of any other importance

Comment: I have removed the line and it still works(I am using chrome btw). check for youself ..http://jsfiddle.net/b6ydm/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select onChange="dropdownTip()" id="select" name="search_type" style="margin-right:10px; margin-top:2px;">
    <option selected="selected" value="fruit_search">fruits</option>    
    <option value="veggies_search">veggies</option>
    <option value="animals_search">animals</option>
    <option value="all_search">all</option>
</select>

<div id="result"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdownTip(){
        var value = document.getElementById('select').value;
        document.getElementByID("result").innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this method did not work for me. Nothing happens when I try to use this method, no errors, nothing prints out.